# display error mesage in paper-input inside a dom-repeat in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

how to enable error message for a paper-input inside a dom-repeat template using polymer 1.0?

my html code is:

```
 <div class = "pt15 itemset2">
     <div class = "alignInline">
    <div class = "w100">
       <paper-input no-label-float value="{{shObj[0].value}}" label = "value" class = "profile_input profItems nopad" type = "text" prevent-invalid-input allowed-pattern = "[0-9\b]"   id = "sharePreVal" maxlength = "30" autofocus on-keyup = "removeInvalid" error-message ="Please enter share value"></paper-input>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class = "pt15 w65 pr30">
   <div class = "alignInline">
      <div class = "w100">
          <paper-input no-label-float label = "description" class = "profile_input profItems nopad" type = "text"  id = "sharePreDesc" value="{{shObj[0].desc}}" on-keyup = "removeInvalid" error-message ="Please enter description"></paper-input>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and my javaScript code inside polymer script as:

```
for(i=0;i<this.shObj.length;i++){
    if (this.shObj[i].desc == '') {
        this.$.sharePreVal.errorMessage = 'Please enter share name';
        this.$.sharePreVal.invalid = true;
        valid = false;
    }
     if (this.shObj[i].value == '') {
         this.$.sharePreDesc.errorMessage='Please enter share description';
         this.$.sharePreDesc.invalid = true;
         valid = false;
     }
 }
```

it displays error as:

```
TypeError: this.$.sharePreVal is undefined
this.$.sharePreVal.errorMessage = 'Please enter share name';
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you. When I started to use Polymer I wanted to validate an input, so the way I found is as follows:

```
     <paper-input-container autovalidate id="containerNombre">
         <label>Nombre de usuario</label>
         <input is="iron-input" id="nombre" bind-value="{{nombre}}" maxlength="5" minlength="2">
         <paper-input-error>{{messageNombre}}</paper-input-error>
     </paper-input-container>

       observers: [
                'nombreChanged(nombre)',
            ],
       nombreChanged: function (nombre) {
            var matches = nombre.match(/\d+/g);
            if (matches != null) {
                this.messageNombre = "¡Solo se permiten letras!";
                this.$.containerNombre.invalid = true; //show message error
            } else {//if matches is ok
                this.$.containerNombre.invalid = false; //hide message error
            }
        }
```